# rs.EOF error can anyone check and fix it pls

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

Can anyone check my code and fixed it ? because
I think there has a problem near at the  ((if rs.EOF))  because i use this method 2times.
and if i run it i got this error:

Error: Operation is not allowed when the object is open.

---

```
Public Sub addBorrower(BCat As String, BIname As String, BImod As String, BFname As String, BLname As String, BBD As String, BDR As String)

    Dim itemid As Integer

    qry2 = "select tblItem_id,item_name,item_model,category_name from tblitem inner join tblcategory on tblcategory.tblcategory_id=tblitem.tblcategory_id where tblitem.item_name='" + BIname + "' and tblitem.item_model='" + BImod + "' and tblcategory.category_name='" + BCat + "'"

    Set rs = conn.Execute(qry2)

    If Not rs.EOF Then 

        itemid = rs.Fields(0).Value
        qry1 = "select * from tblborrowers where tblItem_id=' + itemid + '"
        rs.Open qry1, conn

        If Not rs.EOF Then

            DateReturned = rs.Fields(5).Value
            If DateReturned = Null Then
                MsgBox "Cant add the Borrowers to the item because there's some user who used it that hav'nt returned Yet."
            Else
                qry1 = "insert into tblborrowers(Firstname,Lastname,tblItem_id,date_Borrowed,date_Returned)values('" + BFname + "','" + BLname + "','" + itemid + "','" + BDD + "','" + BDR + "')"
                MsgBox "Successfully added"
            End If

        Else
            qry1 = "insert into tblborrowers(Firstname,Lastname,tblItem_id,date_Borrowed,date_Returned)values('" + BFname + "','" + BLname + "','" + itemid + "','" + BDD + "','" + BDR + "')"
            MsgBox "Successfully added"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry the Item category,Item name and Item model did'nt match or exist. Please check.", vbCritical, "Notification"
    End If

    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did very simple mistake.

You have open the Recordset here

```
Set rs = conn.Execute(qry2)
```

And, again you are opening the same recordset RS here

```
qry1 = "select * from tblborrowers where tblItem_id=' + itemid + '"
    rs.Open qry1, conn
```

If you want to Open the Rs again, then first Close it. Thats why it saying : 
    Operation is not allowed when the object is open.

```
rs.Close
qry1 = "select * from tblborrowers where tblItem_id=' + itemid + '"
    rs.Open qry1, conn
```

Or, Use another Recordset.

Comment: thanks dude i got it.. You give me an answer and idea to solve my other problems hehehe  How can i mark it resolve? i can't find any button.. hehe

Comment: On the beginning of my answer, there is Tick mark named MARK AS ANSWERED. You can click on that, if you find your solution. And, You welcome...